# How to convert all integers in a json file to strings via jq command?

Tags: json, jq

Suppose that we have a `a.json` file. The file contains many attributes.
For example in the file, I just show two attributes "name" and "age".
In fact there are more attributes having numerical values though.

```
{
  "name":[
    "James", 
    "Alek", 
    "Bob"
  ],
  "age":[
    35,
    25,
    23
  ]
  ...//other attributes with numerical values
}
```

How can we convert the file like the following?

```
{
  "name":[
    "James", 
    "Alek", 
    "Bob"
  ],
  "age":[
    "35",
    "25",
    "23"
  ]
  ...//other attributes with numerical values
}
```

Comment: While this could be possible (and safer!) with `jq`, if your JSON is pretty-formatted you can do the job with a simple `sed` command.

Comment: I would like to do the job without specifying any attributes (e.g., "age") since I have a lots of attributes... Still is this possible to do this with `sed`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## A `jq` solution

You can use the `jq`'s [`walk()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#walk(f)) builtin to recursively walk the JSON values, check their [`type`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#type)s and convert the numbers [`tostring()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tostring).

Assuming your JSON is stored in the file `input.json`, the command is like:

```
jq 'walk(if type == "number" then tostring else . end)' input.json
```

It dumps the modified JSON to the screen and its output can be redirector to another file (`> output.json`).

#### If it fails

Most probably, the command above fails with the error message:

```
jq: error: walk/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
```

It means the `walk()` builtin is not (!) built into the `jq` version you use. The issue has been reported two years ago (issue [#1106](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1106)) but it apparently is not a bug but an optional feature. The definition of builtins can be [downloaded](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#definition-of-builtins) from Github's project page. Once downloaded and saved in a local file, the builtins module can be loaded using [`include()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#includeRelativePathString%5B%3Cmetadata%3E%5D;) and used.

Your workflow would look like this:

```
# Download the builtins module (only once) and save it in './builtin.jq'
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedolan/jq/master/src/builtin.jq

# Process the data
jq 'include "./builtin"; walk(if type == "number" then tostring else . end)' input.json > output.json
```

That's all!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!!

Comment: By the way, are there any other directories that I should store the `builtin.jq` in order to avoid `include`, something like `/usr/local/include`?

Comment: The [Modules](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Modules) section of the documentation says that `import` searches for modules in `~/.jq` (and some paths relative to the current directory). Also in the Cookbook there is [a section](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#include-or-import-a-module-and-call-its-functions) where the same information is provided with examples.